# how to place an css image gallery on top of a background image

Tags: html, css, gallery, background-image

I am new to HTML, CSS & co. Currently I am creating a website where I want to create a little Image Gallery with 6 pictures in two rows (3 + 3). There is a background-image underneath.

I followed the instruction on W3 School [CSS Image Gallery](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_gallery.asp), but the images are positioned on top of each other instead inline.

Do you have any solution for that?

*Unfortunately I cannot post any screenshots or codes in here as this is my first post and I don`t have enough reputation.*

Comment: You can make an example at www.jsfiddle.net and paste the url here :)

Comment: Also, add the image anyway and someone will insert it for you, as long as it is relevant.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I didn`t know jsfiddle. Very helpful.
here is the link to the one without the background-image: http://jsfiddle.net/nEza4/
it looks slightly different on my pc, but the gallery effect is the same.

Comment: @Jonas: How can I add the images? when I try to edit my post I get an error: Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

    We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.

Sorry, for all the trouble, but I am still trying to figure out how it works.

Comment: You supply the link to me or any other SO user with more rep than 10. :) Also, you can add code by copy-pasting it into the text field.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant code for inline images in W3's code is the CSS: `float:left`

If all your images are in the same container (or `div` for example), then you need to break the floating with `clear:left`. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vJjgg/

Otherwise, just have two divs with images inside with `float:left` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ug8Zt/